# Associative array, google forms and google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I am trying to add headers of google form fields in a key value pair (associative array) but I am getting an error with my code below:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(<SheetID>).getActiveSheet();
var headers = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,getLastCol(sheet)).getValues();
var values = e.range.getValues();
var assoc = {};

for (var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++){
  assoc[headers[i]] = [values[i]];
}

Logger.log("assoc: " + assoc["Timestamp"]);
```

I am not sure why Timestamp is not being outputted when I try to log it. Can anyone please point out what I am doing incorrectly?

Comment: What is the error, and what line of code is causing the error?  Is this code in an `onEdit()` function?

Comment: In the logs, I get the following: assoc: undefined - not entirely sure why it's coming up as undefined since both headers and values exist. No this code is run onSubmit() function.

Comment: The `getValues()` method returns a 2 dimensional array.  `headers[i]` and `values[i]` gets an inner array that represents all the cell values in a row.  Try using a second index:  `headers[i][columnNumber_Zero_Indexed]`

Comment: Thank you, that sorted it out - can't believe I forgot that.

Answer (score 0):

Since the range is only a single row, you could add the zero index to the end of getValues() so that returns a normal 1 dimensional array.

`var values = e.range.getValues()[0];`